# DebugDiag configuration for catching specific HttpException

Tags: .net, debugging, timeout, httpexception

Does anyone have any experience with setting up DebugDiag to trigger on a specific HttpException? The advanced configuration only allows you to specify the .NET type of the exception, while HttpExceptions are very generic and are used for anything from 404's to timeouts. I'm interested in triggering a dump on page timeout in this case.

Thanks

Mattias

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to investigate using DebugDiag's hang feature, though October is probably a little late to be making this point. :-) Hope it turned out well for you.